# Keeping wifi connection on when android mobile sleeps

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

I am creating networked app, which sends heartbeat to server after some interval. My problem is when mobile is in 'sleep mode', after some time connection is disclosed(probably due to getting wifi off). So as app is unable to send heartbeat, it is also getting disconnected.

Now how to avoid getting wifi off.

I have tried things like `'WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER'`, `WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL` etc etc.

But nothing works?
Has anybody has solved this issue? I will be greatfull, if there is any real example.

Thank You in advance

Reedit:
wifi manager code which i have used.

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
Lock = wifiManager.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "LockTag");
lock.acquire();
```

Comment: Have you used a `WifiLock`?

Comment: yeah, it also didn't work. I have re-edit question with wifilock code for reference.

Comment: Can you try holding a powermanager wakelock also? for preventing system from suspending again.

Comment: i tried but it didnt work for htc mobiles

Answer (score 1):

[Solved]

```
int pol = android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER;
                android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(cr, android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY, pol);
```

I used PowerManager api as follows along with above code & finally it's solved.

```
final PowerManager p = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
l = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "newTAG");
l.acquire();
```

& for releasing this lock, I am overriding onDestroy().
(Note: Though, it is not recommended. Instead of using onDestroy for releasing, onPause() should be used--as per documentation)

Answer (score 0):

Recently I tried,

```
int pol = android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER;
                android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(cr, android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY, pol);
```

It works fine except for HTC mobiles.

Is there any reason for this?